# Image_view displays empty gray window

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not been able to make **image_view** work. Currently, when I run it a gray screen displays rather than an image.

My first thought is that that I don't have the topic correctly entered. I have tried **rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image** and **rosrun image_view image_view image:=/gscam/image_raw**. Both lead to the same result. All of the packages needed are downloaded and compiled.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67198/image_view-displays-empty-gray-window/) by [brein](https://answers.ros.org/users/5156/brein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brendan Andrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/4682/brendan-andrade/) on 2013-07-12**:
you can try running rostopic list which will give you a list of current topics. You may be able to tell which topic you want from the list. It might be /camera/image_raw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked that the topic is being published ([rostopic hz](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_hz))?

Edit: What nodes other than image_view are you running? From your response, I'd guess that you either forgot to start whatever node you're using to publish camera images, or it's failing. [rqt_graph](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt_graph) may help you here.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brein](https://answers.ros.org/users/5156/brein/) on 2013-07-15**:
I used rostopic hz /camera/image, which returned the message 'subscribed to [/camera/image]'. I then did rostopic list -p, which returned nothing, as well as rostopic list -s, where /camera/image appeared. It looks like /camera/image is a subscriber and that nothing is being published to the topic.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-16**:
Most likely, the driver is not contacting the camera successfully, so it has nothing to publish. Check for driver messages in the log.

**Comment by [brein](https://answers.ros.org/users/5156/brein/) on 2013-07-22**:
you guys were right, the camera was not publishing images so that was the problem that had to be fixed. thanks for your help